# WPF application execution path

Tags: wpf

I have developed a WPF application and placed the executables on a network path. I have distributed the shortcut to the application to the users. Now, users can launch the WPF application by running the shortcut. 
In the WPF application, I like to know from what client's drive the application was executed. In other words, I like to know the letter of the drive where the shortcut was placed. Is it possible to get this information? If yes, how?

BTW, I am aware of "Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location" but this returns the path to application, not the path to shortcut.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to find this out. What you could do, though, is add a command-line parameter to the shortcut stating the drive.